# How to add an issue on a github board

Tags: github, github-projects

There are a lot of menu's and + buttons but I've not been able to find any that can be used to just add a new card to the board.  All I've been able to do is add a note.

How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## The UI is a bit confusing

### Do this through the "Issues" tab.

[image]

### Add the issue

### Then move it to the board column

[image]

[image]